# Can we use direct comparison test with sequences with $(-1)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know, this is a really short question but not unuseful by that means. Since for direct comparison test, you need $a_n>0$, I figured that any sequence with a factor of $(-1)^n$, would imply that there are negative terms at odd numbers of $n$, hence you wouldn't be able to use that test. Is this true?

Comment: In fact, the comparison test only applies for series with positive summands. If you have an alternate series, there is a nice sufficient condition : The absolute value of the sequence entries decreases strictly and tends to $0$.

Comment: okay so you can't use direct comparison test on alternate series, great, thank you

Comment: What you can do is test for absolute convergence, see if $|a_n|$ converges,  because absolute convergence implies convergence.